# Blender 2.7 Principled BSDF missing

Tags: shader-nodes

I have seen many blender tutorials in youtube - some people use blender 2.7 and they have a Principled BSDF.  Mine's missing:

[image: BSDF]

Comment: Principled BSDF was added in 2.79. It looks like you're using 2.78.

Comment: oh ye i forgot to change the blender shortcut in my desktop thx